# How to launch Chrome For Testing using ChromeDriver using C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-for-testing

I keep searching on internet from different sources but still unable to launch a specific version of Chrome For Testing using ChromeDriver using C# in VS 2022. Sadly it's not clearly explained on Selenium website. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Finally here is the way Please note I'm running this on VS 2022 of Windows 11

You cannot initialize ChromeDriver with the path to ChromeDriver. Instead, **you have to add the path to ChromeDriver to Windows' user/system variables first**.

After that, you can launch a specific version of Chrome For Testing using this code:

```
 var co = new ChromeOptions();
 co.BrowserVersion = "117"; //here can be 116, 117, 118, etc.
 IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
 // do not use IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("path-to-chromedriver", co);

 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com"); //will download and launch Chrome 117
```

Watch this video for more details: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSmEaOEeusE, but it's in Java. Enjoy coding!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to achieve a multiple driver instances if there is only one exe file?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. You can use the `BinaryLocation` property of the `ChromeOptions` class.

I cannot use Driver Manager or download anything from the internet when running our system.

Our system runs on Windows (development in Win10, production Windows server), targeting .NET6.

I have downloaded the stable versions of Chrome for testing (CFT) and chromedriver (119.0.6045.105).

Let's assume I have downloaded the files to the `c:\test\chrome-for-testing\119.0.6045.105` and `c:\test\chromedriver\119.0.6045.105` folders respectively.

```cs
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"c:\test\chromedriver\119.0.6045.105");

// configure chrome capabilities
var options = new ChromeOptions();    
options.BinaryLocation = @"c:\test\chrome-for-testing\119.0.6045.105\chrome.exe";

// create driver
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
```

And that's it. Hope that helps.